# while uploading the file approx 10 mb I am getting "failed to parse multipart" error

Tags: java, struts, tomcat6

While uploading the file approx 10 MB I am getting "failed to parse multipart" error. I have to upload the file without making any change in the struts config files.I am using struts 1.1 and tomcat 6.0. I suppose the error is in the below line in js:

```
<form action="/dataUploadActionNew" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

But I am not sure about the changes which have to be done.

Thanks

Comment: Any stacktrace server side? OOM ?

Comment: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException:Read timed out at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.paserequest at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.paserequest


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out.

This is not the complete error log but the major errors I get. While uplaoding even the 2 Mb file the browser doesnt accept the file it simply keeps on revolving.

Comment: Sometimes my code works prefectly. Sometimes it gives the multipart error in the tomcat. Does anybody faced the similar issue?

Comment: You seem to have network issues of some sort. Do you have any firewall, proxy, etc... between your browser and the server ?

Comment: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Read timed out
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:429)
 at org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.handleRequest(CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.java:195)
 at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:445)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate

Comment: Hey BGR, thanks for your help. But the issue is not with the speed I guess. But with the browser I guess. Sometimes it uploads and sometimes it doesnt.